# What's the best way to combine an action outside of the UI with an action in the UI?

Tags: design, ios, mobile-application

Working on a picking flow for a warehouse app and I'm having trouble translating the following flow into design

Go to space --> Scan space --> Scan product --> Enter # of units picked

thinking something like this, but I feel like it's missing feedback needed to direct the user thru the flow without making them think - also, with this flow I'm not sure where to add the input field so that user can enter # units picked

Thank you for your help everyone!

[image]

After many iterations and feedback from our team, users and this great online community the project is coming together.

[image: Before and after]

Comment: What is space in this context? Just asking, not a warehouse guy.

Comment: that's a great question. The space is the where the items are stored. So in this case the user would need to go to that location and scan the location barcode to progress to the next screen.

Answer (score 2):

I think it needs a progress tracker. It doesn't have to be horizontal. It can go vertical given that it is a mobile application.

> What Are Progress Trackers?
>   Progress trackers (or progress indicators) display progress through a sequence by breaking it up into multiple logical and numbered steps. They guide the user through a number of steps in order to complete a specified task. Good progress tracker should inform users about following aspects:
>   What steps (or tasks) they have completed (preferably with a proper visual response)
>   Current step they are on (user’s current location within the process).
>   Which and how many steps still remain (preferably with clear designation).

[image]

[(Source)](https://uxplanet.org/progress-trackers-in-ux-design-4319cef1c600)

Comment: I did think about adding a progress tracker - the thing with this flow is that steps 2 - 4 may need to be repeated i.e if the order they are picking contains 100 units of a product, those units could be stored in 4 different spaces . The user would complete the first cycle and then would have to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the user arrives at the third screen you can have a `UIAlertController` with a text field asking the user to enter the quantity. As soon as they do then they can tap the "pick x amount" button.

The reason I am suggesting this and not having a `UITextField` below the button both being active at the same time is that your button is large and tempting for the user to tap and you don't want them accidentally tapping without entering the number.

Comment: hmm this could work - the only thing is the user needs to know how many units they are expected to pick/grab first before they enter the number actually picked/grabbed.thank you

Comment: You could have the recommended number pre-filled in the text field

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your comments, the number of items to pick up is displayed in step 3. They will need to enter a new number only if for some reasons they didn't pick up the right number (maybe there were not enough items).

I would keep the large button with the number of items to pick up so the user can click on it to confirm they picked the right number (which will likely be the majority of cases). I would add a link at the bottom "Correct number" or "I picked a different number" leading the user to a screen where they can indicate the exact number they picked.

Regarding the progress tracker and the need to repeat steps 2 to 4: in step 1, you can add a shortcut to "Use [aisle A3]" (previously scanned space), so the user can skip this step and get directly to step 2.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, we won't be keeping this design because our users will using a scan gun to scan instead of the device's camera. I do like your idea of having a text button at the bottom of the screen to have the user enter the amount of units picked.